# Split a text column as min:sec

Tags: python, pandas, time, split

I have a time details as text in dataframe .

```
dict1={'time' : ['2 min 19 sec','2 min 43 sec','1 min 33 sec','32 sec','40 sec','22 sec']}
df=pd.DataFrame(dict1)


    time
0   2 min 19 sec
1   2 min 43 sec
2   1 min 33 sec
3   32 sec
4   40 sec
5   22 sec
```

I want the output to be generated as

```
      time         updtime
 0  2 min 19 sec    2:19
 1  2 min 43 sec    2:43
 2  1 min 33 sec    1:33
 3  32 sec          0:32
 4  40 sec          0:40
 5  22 sec          0:22
```

I tried splitting the time and i am getting issue in the alignment of data.

```
 df['time'].str.split("min", n =2, expand = True)
```

Output:

```
    0        1
-------------------
0   2       19 sec
1   2       43 sec
2   1       33 sec
3   32 sec  None
4   40 sec  None
5   22 sec  None
```

Row 3,4,5 values should be listed in second column but its listed in 1st column and hence i am unable to join the two columns.
Could anyone share your ideas how to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I have changed the format of the column to be similar with data type `DateTime` and stringify into the expected format

```
>>> df['time'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: f'0 min {x}'if 'min' not in x else x)
>>> df['uptime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%M min %S sec').dt.strftime('%M:%S')
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> df
           time uptime
0  2 min 19 sec  02:19
1  2 min 43 sec  02:43
2  1 min 33 sec  01:33
3  0 min 32 sec  00:32
4  0 min 40 sec  00:40
5  0 min 22 sec  00:22
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. I am using regex to get all the number values, which returns an list, which is joined later on to create a single str.

```
df["updated-time"] = df["time"].apply(lambda x : ":".join(re.findall('\\b\\d+\\b', x)))
```

**Output**

> ```
>   time           uptime
> 0 2 min 19 sec    2:19
> 1 2 min 43 sec    2:43
> 2 1 min 33 sec    1:33
> 3 32 sec          32
> 4 40 sec          40
> 5 22 sec          22
> ```

Comment: instead of 32 it should display as 0:32, 0:40 etc.. for the entries which has no min it should update as 0 and then the sec value.